# Editable ListView wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview

I am trying to create editable listview dynamically. Need to display array of string as source. when we are clicking on the item it should be editable.

Problem: No errors but no items are displaying.

```
 Style tableStyle = _resourceDictionary["TableStyle"] as Style;

        ItemsPanelTemplate itemsPanelTemplate = _resourceDictionary["ItemsPanelTemplate"] as ItemsPanelTemplate;

        FrameworkElementFactory factoryPanel = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(UniformGrid));
        factoryPanel.SetValue(UniformGrid.ColumnsProperty, 5);
        ItemsPanelTemplate template = new ItemsPanelTemplate();
        template.VisualTree = factoryPanel;

        ListView simpleTable = new ListView();
        //  simpleTable.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn { Header = "Values" });
        simpleTable.Style = tableStyle;
        simpleTable.ItemsPanel = template;
        _table = simpleTable;

 string aa = "aa,xx,cc,vv,bbb,hh,gg,rr,tt,yy,uu,ooo";
_table.ItemsSource = aa.ToString().Split(',');
```

Xaml

```
<Style x:Key="TableStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ControlBackgroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
                <ListView>
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView >
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Databases" Width="498">
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBox  Text="{Binding .}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Why don't you use a DataGrid?

Comment: i am new to WPF. DOnt know how to use datagrid dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to edit data in a tabular grid you should use the [DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/datagrid) control. It is basically an editable `GridView`.

Create a class that represents a row:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And set the `ItemsSource` property of the `DataGrid` to a collection of such objects:

```
string aa = "aa,xx,cc,vv,bbb,hh,gg,rr,tt,yy,uu,ooo";
_table.ItemsSource = aa.Split(',').Select(x => new Item() { Value = x });
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="_table" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Databases" Binding="{Binding Value}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating another `ListView` inside the `ControlTemplate` of the first one and that's what creates the confusion:

```
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding EditableItems}" >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView >
                <GridViewColumn Header="Databases" Width="498">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox  Text="{Binding .}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score -2):

I think the datatype you are using is wrong 
If you want your list can have a edit function you should use the observableCollection in this case

Comment: OC can be added or remove values